# Wrong marker being retrieved in gmap3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

In gmap3 google maps library, I am trying to make a function that makes a marker with an infowindow.

http://gmap3.net/api-infowindow.html

```
function addMarker(map, marker, content) {
    map.marker(marker)
    .infowindow({
        'content' : content
    })
    .then(function (infowindow) {
        var map = this.get(0);
        var marker = this.get(1);  // <---- this gets the first marker on both times I call addMarker, i.e. uluru
        marker.addListener('click', function(event, data) {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

    var map = $('#map')
      .gmap3({
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
      });

    addMarker(map, {
        position: uluru
    }, "text");
    addMarker(map, {
        position: {lat: 48.8620722, lng: 2.352047}
    }, "text2");
});
```

This is what I have, but the problem is, in the top, where I try to get a marker (i put a comment in the code), it seems to be referencing the wrong marker. Both times I call it, it references the first marker I make. As a result, if I click the first marker on the map, I get both infowindows showing up on that marker.

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "get" function retrieves the chained results from the beginning, indexes will never change.

Store it locally in your function using the "then"

```
function addMarker(map, marker, content) {
  var gmMarker;
  map
      .marker(marker)
      .then(function (m) {
        gmMarker = m;
      })
      .infowindow({
        'content' : content
      })
      .then(function (infowindow) {
        var map = this.get(0);
        gmMarker.addListener('click', function(event, data) {
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      });
}
```